# Obfuscating password in batch script

Tags: security, batch-file, passwords, cmd

I have a batch script with a password sitting in it as part of a command that requires credentials that I do not want to prompt for credentials. I am not worried about external threats, but I don't really want a co-worker going in there and seeing that password. While I trust them not to abuse it, I'd rather not have it there at all.

I was able to do this pretty easily with PowerShell by just storing a secure string in a text file. Pretty basic, but at least there's no plain text passwords laying around. That's all I really need.

How can I obfuscate a password in a batch script?

Comment: you can't hide a password effectively without 3rd party tools in batch.

Comment: you can try to encode it with `certutil`  to hex or base64 (or both) -> http://ss64.com/nt/certutil.html  .That's the easiest thing that comes to me right now.

Comment: @npocmaka That could work, I don't really even need to encrypt it... just anything that's not plain text.

Comment: the only issue is that you'll need temporary files to extract the password...check `-encode/-decode` and `-encodehex\-decodehex` options.You can also try to store the password as binary in the registry.

Comment: @npocmaka That works well enough for me. If you'd like to add that as an answer, please do.

Comment: Just to clarify: do you want password to be obfuscated from batch file or from console output?

Answer (score 7):

You could also hide the password in an *alternate data stream*:

First, add the somewhat secret password to an alternate data stream of your script:

```
echo somewhatsecretpassword>script.bat:pwd
```

Here's how to retrieve the password into the variable `%p%`:

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %i in (script.bat:pwd) do set p=%i
```

From within the batch file itself you may use something like:

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%i in (%~0:pwd) do set p=%%i
```

**This is not secure!**

Please consider:

- This is not secure!
- Alternate data streams do not get copied everywhere (FAT)
- Passwords containing special characters may need to be escaped in order to get written correctly to the stream
- ... it is not secure

Comment: I would recommend using command-line immediately in `FOR` to avoid storing password in environment variables.

Comment: nitpicky grammar: 'You could also hide the password in a[n] alternate data stream'.  the 'an' form is always used when the following word begins with a vowel sound (compare 'a engine' with 'an engine').  Solution is just what I was looking for though - just enough to prevent the superficially curious and for the secret to be lost if the file is copied away.

Comment: @Charemer I just corrected it, I did get it right on the second line....

Answer (score 1):

Another option might be to obfuscate a "password", which is not secure at all but might be sufficent in certain situations

```
:main
set a=pas
set b=rd
set /p input=
if %input%==%a%swo%b% goto start
:start
<your code here>
goto main
```

the password is "password", but it's a bit obfuscated.